# Отключить синхронизацию времени в Debian

Tags: linux, debian, ntp

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно полностью отключить синхронизацию времени в Debian?
Я пробовал уже следующее:

```
systemctl stop ntp
systemctl disable ntp
timedatectl set-ntp 0
systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd
systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd
```

Но время всё равно синхронизируется после перезагрузки.
Что ещё может выполнять синхронизацию времени?

Comment: А дебиан где запущен?

Comment: а статус вышеназванных демонов после запуска смотрел — может их кто по зависимостям подтягивает?

Comment: @andreymal, чисто ради интереса — а какая разница?

Comment: @Fat-Zer если дебиан это гостевая ОС, то менять время принудительно может хост, например в виртуалбоксе

Comment: `tcpdump` или `wireshark` или `ss -a` могут помочь найти активные подключения, потом по цепочке ищете от куда идут.

Comment: а по крону случайно не вызывается ntpdate - для синхронизации?